# Penny plain / penny coloured

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence

> "He used to bring us a comic for a half-penny plain and a penny coloured."

Why does the 'plain' go after half-penny, not before a comic, if it means black and white and has nothing to do with a half-penny?

Comment: Sounds good to me as written—parallel structures.

Comment: "He used to bring us a comic for a half-penny **for the** plain **edition** and a penny **for the** coloured **one**."

Answer (score 2):

The price of the comic was a halfpenny for an uncoloured one, a penny if it was coloured.

*A penny plain and twopence coloured* was a well-known phrase in the 19th century. I don't know whether Robert Louis Stevenson originated it, but he used it as the title of an essay about the toy theatres (using paper cut-out figures) that he had played with as a boy. The child could either colour in their own figures or buy them ready-coloured.

Comment: And Stevenson despised those children who bought the already coloured versions (though this particular boyhood customer of Pollock's on Monmouth Street can recall the essay's appearing even in the playbooks that came with the character and set sheets printed in colour).